# Symfony 2 array into form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So I explain my problem
As we can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkZW0.png), I have two entities (Users and Module) linked by a ManyToMany association with two extra fields (Note and observation). It seems that it’s impossible to do this kind of relation with symphony. To solve this problem I created a third entity (Result) which is linked to others by a ManyToOne relation. And I defined the 2 extras fields as attribute for the third Entity.

Now I have to make a form which save into database the result for a student. I don’t like to save one by one the result for each student, but I want to have (as shown on [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Ehv.png)) one form which contain all users, and with only one submit, I save the result for all users in the form to database.

Here is the code of my entities, controllers and forms:

Entity User.php

```
class User extends BaseUser {
protected $id;
/**@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\ScholarityBundle\Entity\Result", mappedBy="markUserIds")     */
protected $markUserIds;
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->markUserIds = new ArrayCollection();
}
public function getMarkUserIds()    {
    return $this->markUserIds;
}
```

Entity Module.php

```
class Module{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\ScholarityBundle\Entity\Result", mappedBy="markClassCoursesIds")
 */
protected $markClassCoursesIds;
public function __construct()    {
    $this->markClassCoursesIds = new ArrayCollection();
}
public function getId()    {
    return $this->id;
}    
public function addMarkClassCoursesId(\App\ScholarityBundle\Entity\Result $markClassCoursesIds)    {
    $this->markClassCoursesIds[] = $markClassCoursesIds;
    return $this;
}
public function getMarkClassCoursesIds()    {
    return $this->markClassCoursesIds;
}
```

}

Entity Result.php

```
class Result{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=2)
 */
private $mark;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $observation;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\SettingBundle\Entity\Module", inversedBy="markClassCoursesIds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_courses_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $markClassCoursesId;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="markUserIds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mark_user_Id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $markUserId;

public function getId()    {
    return $this->id;
}
public function setMark($mark)    {
    $this->mark = $mark;
    return $this;
}
public function getMark()    {
    return $this->mark;
}
public function setObservation($observation)    {
    $this->observation = $observation;
    return $this;
}
public function getObservation()    {
    return $this->observation;
}
public function setMarkClassCoursesId(\App\SettingBundle\Entity\Module $markClassCoursesId = null)    {
    $this->markClassCoursesId = $markClassCoursesId;
    return $this;
}
public function getMarkClassCoursesId()    {
    return $this->markClassCoursesId;
}
public function setMarkUserId(\AppBundle\Entity\User $markUserId = null)    {
    $this->markUserId = $markUserId;
    return $this;
}
public function getMarkUserId()    {
    return $this->markUserId;
}
```

}

Controller ResultController.php

```
class ResultController extends Controller{
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $result = new Result();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
    $users= $repository->findAllStudent();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ResultType(), $result, array('users' => $users));
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($result);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('scholarity_coursesmark')); 
        }
    }
    return $this->render('AppScholarityBundle:result:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    )); 
}
```

}

Form CustomResultType.php

```
class CustomResultType extends AbstractType{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('mark');
    $builder->add('observation');
    $builder->add('markUserId');
}
```

}

Form ResultType.php

```
class ResultType extends AbstractType{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)    {
    foreach ($options['users'] as $user) {
        $builder->add('markUserId' . $user->getId(), CustomResultType::class, [
            'data' => $user,
        ]);
    }
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)    {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'App\ScholarityBundle\Entity\Result',
        'users' => null,
    ));
}
public function getName()    {
    return 'result';
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post the code of you entities and relations here ?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy using Symfony's Form component. First you need to create a custom type, eg `UserModuleType` which represents a single user (or in your last picture: one row).

Now you can create another type, let's call it `MultipleUserModuleType` (can probably be named better). Inside that you can either do something like

```
foreach ($options['users'] as $user) {
    $builder->add('usermodule' . $user->getId(), UserModuleType::class, [
        'data' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

Or directly use [`CollectionType`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/collection.html) like so (untested)

```
$builder->add('usermodules', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => UserModuleType::class,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try to apply it, I have this error **Neither the property "markUserId3" nor one of the methods "getMarkUserId3()", "markUserId3()", "isMarkUserId3()", "hasMarkUserId3()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class “AppBundle\Entity\Result”**. You can see my entities, controllers and forms class above.

Comment: @kabisko I can only properly answer you on Monday, sorry. You can set `mapped` to false on markUserId3

Comment: Now this is my ResultType.php content:
`foreach ($options['users'] as $user) {
            $builder->add('markUserId' . $user->getId(), CustomResultType::class, [
                'label' => $user->getUsername(),
      'data' => $user,
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'markUserId'),
            ]);
        }`

Comment: In my CustomResultType I have this one:
`public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('mark', 'text' , ['required' => false, 'mapped' => false]);
    $builder->add('observation', 'text' , ['required' => false, 'mapped' => false]); 
}`
But when I submit my request, I can only access to the user value and not the **mark** and **observation** value